# How to fix duplicate console when using TFT monitor?

Tags: pitft

Using a [2423](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2423) PiTFT monitor from Adafruit.

Trying to set up my Pi so that it displays a console without auto-login at boot while allowing me to run `chromium-browser` using `xinit`.

I followed the [guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-8-pitft-capacitive-touch/easy-install-2#installer-script-3-5) to configure the monitor selecting "PiTFT as HDMI Mirror (Best for Raspbian Full/PIXEL)" to enable `fbcp`. My understanding is that `fbcp` is required to run `chromium-browser`.

I appended `fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:VGA8x8` to `/boot/cmdline.txt` and set the resolution to 320x240 (`hdmi_cvt=320 240 60 1 0 0 0`) in `/boot/config.txt`.

I installed `xserver-xorg-legacy` and `xserver-xorg-input-evdev` to fix `xinit` and touch bugs.

I deleted `20-calibration.conf` and `40-libinput.conf` in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and edited `10-evdev.conf`.

```
Option "SwapAxes" "1"
Option "InvertY" "1"
Option "InvertX" "0"
Option "EmulateThirdButton" "1"
Option "EmulateThirdButtonTimeout" "750"
Option "EmulateThirdButtonMoveThreshold" "30"
```

Problem is, when the Pi boots, everything works fine at first, but a few seconds later, the console gets duplicated (see picture). Looks like a window with another console is added on top of the console that first appeared. How can I fix this?

Also, is there a way to get `chromium-browser` to launch from the console without installing `xserver-xorg-legacy`?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Removing `fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:VGA8x8` from `/boot/cmdline.txt` solves the duplicate console problem but the boot sequence isn’t display anymore. How can I display the boot sequence (the lines with OK etc...)?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved it.

Had to run `sudo systemctl disable fbcp.service` to disable `fbcp` at boot.

Then, I created a `run.sh` script that only runs `fbcp` when needed.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/fbcp &
xinit /usr/bin/chromium-browser --app="file:///home/pi/index.html" --kiosk --window-position=0,0 --window-size=320,240
```